# bootstrap 3 div's background image zoom on hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I spent hours to find the proper way with CSS to add zoom effect when hover on a div which has background image. I did try this code and modified, but still doesn't works

```
.zoom_img img{margin:50px;
height:100px;
width:100px;
-moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.5s ease-in; 
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in; 
-o-transition:-o-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.zoom_img img:hover{
-moz-transform:scale(2); 
-webkit-transform:scale(2);
-o-transform:scale(2);
}
```

my code is [here](http://www.bootply.com/cG6mrILVvc)

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know if that is what you expect to do. But in this way it is working:

```
.zoom_img
{
    height:300px;
    background-image: url(http://desktopbackgroundshq.com/backgrounds/animal-bird-animal-backgrounds-animal-bird-25907.jpg);
    background-position: 0% 25%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.zoom_img:hover{
    -moz-transform:scale(2); 
    -webkit-transform:scale(2);
    -o-transform:scale(2);
}
```

code: http://www.bootply.com/N3vP4pzxTT

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.tmbMargin:hover .tmb1 {
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
}
```